# Вывод данных из mysql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте!Подскажите как сделать вывод записей по очередно из mysql.Имеются сообщения пользователей!У каждого уникальный id!Как можно сделать что бы он php выводил как они там стоят а по id.Начиная с самого большого и заканчивая самым маленьким.Заранее спасибо!Если имеется пример подкиньте пожалуйста разобраться!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Здравствуйте.*

Вывод с mysql по очереди можно циклом, таким вот образом:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message_users ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo "Сообщение: ".$row['mess']."<br>
        Пользователь :".$row['login'];
}
```

Пробуйте так.

Answer (score 0):

Запрос к базе

```
order by 'id' desc
```